# Calculating average value for each pixel across multiple images in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do you calculate the average value for each pixel across multiple images in GEE?

I thought about adding all the images and then dividing by the number of images but there may be pixels with no data in some of the images.

```
var GYav1 = GY13.add(GY14);
var GYav2 = GYav1.add(GY15);
var GYav3 = GYav2.add(GY16);
var GYav4 = GYav3.add(GY17);
var GYav5 = GYav4.add(GY18);
var GYav6 = GYav5.add(GY19);
var GYav7 = GYav6.add(GY20);

var GYav = GYav7.divide(8);
```

Comment: We can't reproduce your workflow, because we don't have access to (for example) `GY13`. This question is likely too broad for this forum. However, a good jumping off point for you is to look into Reducers, which can be applied to image collections: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_intro

Comment: Just use the reducers ic.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_image_collection

Answer (score 3):

In Earth Engine, reducers automatically handle missing (masked) data, so the `mean` reducer will take the mean of all the pixels actually present.

```js
var GYav = ee.ImageCollection([
  GY13,
  GY14,
  GY15,
  GY16,
  GY17,
  GY18,
  GY19,
  GY20,
]).mean();
```